# What does this jQuery snippet do (and why)?

Tags: jquery

```
$("div", $("body")).length
```

Saw something like it in qUnit documentation and I've never seen anything like it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument is the context as in below syntax,

> `jQuery( selector [, context] )`
>
> ```
> selector: A string containing a selector expression
>
> context: A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context
> ```

Which basically is defined as follows,

> By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting
>   at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for
>   the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Couldn't even figure out what to look for in the docs because I didn't realize it was a "context" option.